# How to create an empty row after a specific index?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a table that gets its values from a JSON service. I want to create an empty row (or an empty `<tr></tr>`) after the 6th and 11th rows, but I cannot do it. How can I do it?

```
{altmanzscoring.titles.map((val, i) => (
    <tr>
        {val.title == "Altman Z' Puan-İmalatçı Firmalar" ? (
            <td style={{ color: '#007FB2', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{val.title}</td>
        ) : val.title == "Altman Z' Puan-İmalat Harici Firmalar" && i != 13 ? (
            <td style={{ color: '#007FB2', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{val.title}</td>
        ) : (
            <td>{val.title}</td>
        )}
        {val.values[0].value == 'Ortalama İflas Riski' ? (
            <td style={{ color: '#ebc634' }}>{val.values[0].value}</td>
        ) : val.values[0].value == 'Düşük İflas Riski' ? (
            <td style={{ color: '#47d14c' }}>{val.values[0].value}</td>
        ) : val.values[0].value == 'Düşük İflas Riski' ? (
            <td style={{ color: '#e63c41' }}>{val.values[0].value}</td>
        ) : (
            <td>{val.values[0].value}</td>
        )}
        {val.values[1].value == 'Ortalama İflas Riski' ? (
            <td style={{ color: '#ebc634' }}>{val.values[1].value}</td>
        ) : val.values[1].value == 'Düşük İflas Riski' ? (
            <td style={{ color: '#47d14c' }}>{val.values[1].value}</td>
        ) : val.values[1].value == 'Düşük İflas Riski' ? (
            <td style={{ color: '#e63c41' }}>{val.values[1].value}</td>
        ) : (
            <td>{val.values[1].value}</td>
        )}
    </tr>
))}
```

Note: `i` for index.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't add an empty tr, but if you want, just test the index and if the index is a multiple of 5 that case render an additional empty row.

Alternatively you have these options:

1. You could use the `tr: nth-child(5n) {margin-cotton: 5px}` css selector to add room between the rows.
2. you can use multiple `<tbody>` tags (one for every group) and add space there